# How to delete one out of two admin accounts?

Tags: kubuntu, administrator

I recently installed Kubuntu 16.04 on a new laptop. Because of some confusion, I created an admin account with my real name. I then created *another* admin account with a less personal name. I now want to get rid of (delete) the first admin account.

I went into Kubuntu's User Accounts GUI. There, I could remove admin privileges easily from the account I want to delete. But then when I actually tried to delete the user, I got this response:

[image: Kubuntu User Accounts warning]

Why does the system claim that the other user "is using the system right now" when that isn't true?

Is there a safe way to delete the other user? A terminal-based solution is welcome.

Comment: Have you checked the output of `w` command?

Comment: `who` just shows the account I want to keep. No one else.

Comment: What about using command line for removal, do you get a same error there too? `userdel` lets you know about process that is being used by that user: `userdel: user foo is currently used by process 2491`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `userdel` command has a `-f` option to force delete the user, so typing

```
userdel -f *Name*
```

should delete it.

If that does not work, edit `/etc/passwd` with your favorite text editor. You should find something like

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash  
m:x:0:100::/home/m:/bin/bash
```

(there are many more entries) now search for the user you want to delete. Once found, change the first 0 to another number. This is the UID of the User, and the UID 0 represents root. Once changed you can just use

```
deluser *Name*
```

to delete it.